# bootstrap 4 tabs with buttons with active class not working

Tags: button, bootstrap-4, tabs

i have a small issue concerning my bootstrap 4 tabs:

My intention is too switch between buttons like this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwQamK but with bootstrap.

```
  <div id="tab" class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
    <a href="#prices" class="btn btn-primary active" data-toggle="tab">
      <input type="radio" />Prices
    </a>
    <a href="#features" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab">
      <input type="radio" />Features
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="prices">Prices content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="features">Features Content</div>
  </div>
```

Currently the toggle between the tab content is not working!

Here is my codepen:

https://codepen.io/user1010/pen/mYQvVo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### With .nav-pills

You can use `.nav-pills`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#pills

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav nav-pills">
        <a href="#prices" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill">
            Prices
        </a>
        <a href="#features" class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill">
            Features
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="prices">Prices content</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="features">Features Content</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/dxzaufho/12/

#### With btn-group and custom styles

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav btn-group">
        <a href="#prices" class="btn active" data-toggle="tab">
            Prices
        </a>
        <a href="#features" class="btn" data-toggle="tab">
            Features
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="prices">Prices content</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="features">Features Content</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

```css
.btn-group.nav {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.btn-group .btn.active {
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: #fff;
}
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/dxzaufho/19/

Regarding to your issue that your tab is not working, I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/28854) in Github. Currently it looks like you need to have either `.nav` or `.list-group` as the tab's parent class, otherwise the tab won't work properly.

Comment: Hi david, thx about your solution, but my intention is to use buttons solely for the grouped design. lets see maybe there will be a solution on github. great contribution

Answer (score 0):

It looks like instead of being inputs that you can just use the text and it switches between content.

```
  <div id="tab" class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
    <a href="#prices" class="btn btn-primary active" data-toggle="tab">
      Prices
    </a>
    <a href="#features" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab">
      Features
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="prices">Prices content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="features">Features Content</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what about the effect visual toggle button effect tho, or better said the class switch btn-primary to btn-default.

Comment: When I make this adjustment and run it in your codepen example I think that it does do the class switches. Or I may be mistaken

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4.3.1 working tabs as radio buttons - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Eugene82/6qwxy9vo/4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[name="intervaltype"]').click(function () {
      $(this).tab('show');
      $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 


<div class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<div>
    <input id="optDaily" checked name="intervaltype" type="radio" data-target="#scheduleDaily">
    <label for="optDaily">Daily</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="optWeekly" name="intervaltype" type="radio" data-target="#scheduleWeekly">
    <label for="optWeekly">Weekly</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="optMonthly" name="intervaltype" type="radio" data-target="#scheduleMonthly">
    <label for="optMonthly">Monthly</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="scheduleDaily" class="tab-pane active">Daily</div>
    <div id="scheduleWeekly" class="tab-pane">Weekly</div>
    <div id="scheduleMonthly" class="tab-pane">Montly</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The group buttons worked very well on 4.31 but after I did an upgrade on bootstrap 4.4 or 4.4.1, on refresh they get active all and only after clicking each button they start to work properly.

I suggest you to try to use bootstrap 4.3.1 with the example from @Yevgeniy Afanasyev